# WPF CancellationTokenSource not working

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I use this code for running tasks synchronously

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
//cts is a CancellationTokenSource();
foreach (var test in Tests)
{
    var t1 = new Task<string>(t => test.Run(), cts.Token);
    t1.Strat();
    result.Append(t1.Result);
}
```

I call `cts.Cancel()` from a different thread and i can see that the token is updated:
`cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested == true`
But the task keep running and even the next one starts...

what am i missing?

thanks!

Comment: this should be a great reading...http://johnbadams.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/understanding-cancellationtokensource-with-tasks/

Comment: Task cancellation has a cooperative model where the task needs to actively participate in the cancellation process. The task needs to check the token and abort when it is safe to do so.

Comment: What's the point in using tasks in the first place if all you're going to do is synchronously wait for each one to finish?  You're better off just removing all of the task code entirely.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If this property is true, it only guarantees that cancellation has been **requested**.
>   It **does not guarantee that every registered handler has finished executing**, nor that cancellation requests have finished propagating to all registered handlers. Additional synchronization may be required, particularly in situations where related objects are being canceled concurrently.